# Factoring a binary relation into functions

Tags: functions, relations

Let $r$ be a binary relation. Can we assert that there are (monovalued) functions $f$ and $g$ such that

1. $r = f\circ g^{-1}$?
2. $r = f^{-1}\circ g$?

Here $\circ$ is the relational composition, that is $$q\circ p = \{ (x,y) \mid \exists t:((x,t)\in p\land(t,y)\in q) \}$$ for every binary relations $p$, $q$.

Comment: Do $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ denote relations or functions?

Comment: @ArnaudD. $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ are in general not monovalued and thus are relations not functions.

Comment: @porton You could start your inquiry by giving it a try on $r=\{0,1\}^2$.

Comment: @drhab yes, I know. I'm just not used to the notation $f^{-1}$ in this sense, so I just wanted to clarify the meaning : is $f^{-1}=\{(f(x),x)\}$?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes $f^{-1}$ is the set of pairs $(f(x),x)$

Comment: @porton Do you want the two identities to hold simultaneously? I thought you were asking about two separate things.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I do not want the two identities to hold simultaneously. I asked about two separate things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always write them in the first way : if $r\subset X\times Y$, take $g:r\to X$ to be the first projection and $f:r\to Y$ to be the second. Then $g^{-1}=(x,(x,y))\in X\times r$, so
$$f\circ g^{-1}=\{(x,y)\mid \exists (x',y')\in r : (x,(x',y'))\in g^{-1}\wedge ((x',y'),y)\in f\}=r,$$
because the first condition is equivalent to $x=x'$ and the second to $y=y'$.

On the other hand, the second way does not always work. Indeed, if $f,g$ are two functions $X\to Y$, then
$$f^{-1}\circ g=\{(x,x')\mid \exists y :(x,y)\in g \wedge (y,x')\in f^{-1}\}=\{(x,x')\mid g(x)=f(x')\}.$$
In particular, if we can find $a,b\in X$ such that $(a,a),(a,b),(b,b)$ are all in $r$, then we must have
$$f(a)=g(a)=f(b)=g(b),$$
so that we must also have $(b,a)\in r$. In particular, any relation that is reflexive but not symmetric, such as a non-trivial partial order, cannot be of this form.