# Factoring proximity space into two closure operators

Tags: general-topology

A question similar to my previous question [Factoring a binary relation into functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2414159/4876):

Let $\delta$ be a [proximity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_space).
Can we assert that there are [preclosures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preclosure_operator) $f$ and $g$ such that

1. $\delta = f\circ g^{-1}$?
2. $\delta = f^{-1}\circ g$?

Here $r\mapsto r^{-1}$ is the notation for reverse relation.

Here $\circ$ is the relational composition, that is $$q\circ p = \{ (x,y) \mid \exists t:((x,t)\in p\land(t,y)\in q) \}$$ for every binary relations $p$, $q$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not possible. The second condition already implies that both preclosures are indiscrete.

$(A, B) ∈ f^{-1} ∘ g$ if and only if there is a set $C$ such that $(A, C) ∈ g$ and $(C, B) ∈ f^{-1}$, i.e. $g(A) = C = f(B)$.

Let $x, y ∈ X$. We have $\{x\} \mathrelδ \{x, y\} \mathrelδ \{y\}$, and so $g(\{y\}) = f(\{x, y\}) = g(\{y\})$ (we are also using the symmetry of $δ$). So $g(\{x\}) ∋ y$ and $y$ was arbitrary, so $g(\{x\}) = X$. The point $x$ was also arbitrary, and a symmetric argument works for $f$.

Another trivial reason that works for both cases is that $∅$ is always closed, so $(∅, ∅) ∈ (f^{-1} ∘ g) ∩ (f ∘ g^{-1})$ for all preclosures $f$, $g$, but $∅ \mathrel{δ} ∅$ holds for no proximity $δ$.

Comment: I do **not** ask that both conditions hold simultaneously. These two conditions make two separate questions

Comment: @porton: The first part of the answer shows that 2 is almost impossible, and second part shows that 1 and 2 separately are impossible for trivial reasons.